# Constructor.newInstance() behaving differently in a JUnit vs actual runtime

Tags: java, reflection, junit, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to use `java.lang.reflect` methods, in a RCP plug-in project to create a new instance of an object. If I use this:

```
constructorList[0].newInstance();
```

It works fine during runtime, (Running through the RCP App), but the line of code fails in a JUnit with: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`

If I use this instead:

```
constructorList[0].newInstance(((Object) null));
```

It works fine running the JUnit, but fails with during runtime with: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`

The only difference seems to be the code running within a plug-in vs a standalone JUnit.
Does anyone know if this would probably be the root cause? I'm not sure on how to setup my JUnit to run as a JUnit Plug-in, so I haven't been able to test it out.

The JavaDoc for the newInstance method:

> ...
>
> If the number of formal parameters required by the underlying
>   constructor
>        * is 0, the supplied `initargs` array may be of length 0 or null.
>
> @param initargs array of objects to be passed as arguments to
>        * the constructor call; values of primitive types are wrapped in
>        * a wrapper object of the appropriate type (e.g. a float
>        * in a {@link java.lang.Float Float})
>
> ...

Comment: Are you sure that `constructorList[0]` contains the same `Constructor` instance in both cases?

Comment: Does the method that returns the constructorList guarantee a particular ordering of the results?

Comment: @AndyTurner - Yes, I've tried by sending in the same object at runtime & the same during the JUnit. The class does not have a declared constructor, in fact none of the classes that I expect to go through this have declared constructors, so the size of the `constructorList` is always 1 & I'm always invoking the default constructor at index 0.

Comment: @HankD - Probably not, but in both cases there's always just one constructor in the list.

Comment: Honestly, the only explanation I can think of is that you somehow are loading two different versions of the class in these cases (this isn't as farfetched as it sounds, because Eclipse RCP uses OSGi, which does some tricks with classloading). If the class has no declared constructors and isn't an inner class, `constructorList[0].newInstance(((Object) null))` shouldn't work in any circumstances.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - so the one I was using to pass into my JUnit was an inner class. That was the problem. I moved it to it's own file & it's working now. Thanks for point it out about the inner class. Can you reply to the question as an answer so I can mark it as 'Accepted'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, the only explanation I can think of is that you somehow are loading two different versions of the class in these cases (this isn't as farfetched as it sounds, because Eclipse RCP uses OSGi, which does some tricks with classloading). If the class has no declared constructors and isn't an inner class, `constructorList[0].newInstance(((Object) null))` shouldn't work in any circumstances.